# Retrieve Userform textbox value from document vba

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, textbox, userform

A simple question for which I didn't find any answer yet:
I have a Word template document with several UserForms.

Now on AutoNew() a new document based on this template should first read the values from the hidden userforms (the current values are stored somewhere in the template) into global variables for further processing.
Now **how can vba read the values in the userforms from the document without usually unnecessary to show the userforms** ? These userforms are only there to change values if [rarely] desired and should not be automatically displayed (they are opened through controls which later disappear as soon as everything is OK).

My few trials all led to errors:

```
Sub Fertigstellen()

Load Empfängerdaten         ' proposition from Raymond Wu
Dim X
' X = ActiveDocument.Forms("Empfängerdaten.QL4").Text    ' error 438
' X = ActiveDocument.Forms("Empfängerdaten").QL4.Text    ' error 438
' X = ActiveDocument.QL4.Text                            ' error 438
' X = ActiveDocument.Empfängerdaten.QL4.Text             ' error 438
' X = ActiveDocument.Content("QL4").Text                 ' compiling error
' X = ActiveDocument.Empfängerdaten.QL4.Text             ' error 438
' X = ActiveDocument.UserControl("QL4").Text             ' compiling error
If X Like "CH" Then       ' alle Daten sind vorhanden
    Stop
End If

QR_Dialog.Show
```

End Sub

What I need is which command to use (if there is any).

All methods I could find are only able to read values from textboxes enbedded in the document itself. The documents's code doesn't find the userforms' textboxes.

However, I need to use userforms which are hidden when printing the document.
The values from the userforms are only used for generating a QR code, they should not appear anywhere else. Note that MS Word doesn't appear to have an *****Activedocument.Forms![MyField].Value***** property to access userforms (unlike Access or Excel).

NB: the reverse is no problem: from the userforms it's very easy to fill the global variables on opening or closing them.

Comment: `Load UserformName` first then you can access it without showing the userform? Note: Is storing the values in [CustomDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties) an option?

Comment: Or [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.variables) collection..

Comment: Please, show us how did you try obtaining the text box in discussion text. Should we understand that these text boxes keep some text manually placing there using their Text property?

Comment: I inserted my few non-working trials. Using CustomDocumentProperties does not seem me to be praticable; I am already using global variables but the problem is that they are void upon opening the document.

Comment: @Bughater Have you then tried `Load UserformName` and access it's property? It should be hidden until you use `Show` method so you should `Unload` later if you are only loading it to retrieve the values.

Comment: Yes I did, but the question is how to access the data therein. If necessary I could modify the form's UserForm_Initialize() sub in order to export the values to the global variables, then unload it. Hopefully this will not be necessary.

Comment: Assuming you want to access a textbox control called `TextBox1` then try `Load UserformName: globalVar = UserformName.Controls("TextBox1").Text` or `globalVar = UserformName.TextBox1.Text`. Note, you need to ping the person you are replying to with `@name` otherwise we will not receive any notification @Bughater

Comment: If this works then you could make a Sub for this purpose so you just need to do something like `Load UserformName: UserformName.UpdateGlobal` in your AutoNew sub.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite as simple as my question:
I found it in [this Excel blog](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5008-excel-vba-check-if-userform-textbox-is-empty-not-empty.html).
For me highly surprising (as I'm mainly involved with Access) is that Word doesn't need a "userform" to be specified - its name is sufficient !

The following code now just needs to be adapted to the different QL# textboxes, the contents of which need to be checked case by case:

```
Sub Fertigstellen()
Dim fTextBox As Object
For Each fTextBox In Empfängerdaten.Controls
    If TypeName(fTextBox) = "TextBox" Then
    Select Case fTextBox.Name
        Case "QL4"
            If fTextBox.Text Like "ABC" Then
                ' OK
            Else
                Debug.Print fTextBox.Name & ": " & fTextBox.Text
            End If
        ' … … …
        Case Else
            Debug.Print fTextBox.Name & " should be implemented"
    End Select
        End If
Next
' … … …
End Sub
```

On this basis it should probably also be possible to access only one single textbox, but I don't need to as all userform's values must be verified.

Thanks for the hints anyway.